# How to limit the size of array submitted via POST request in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to handle POST requests with an array of objects in their body as follows:

```json
[
  {"path":"./../../", ...},
  {"path":"./../../", ...},
  {"path":"./../../", ...},
  ...
]
```

I haven't found any way to set a validation rule that will limit the max length of such an array, that is located in the root of the POST request body, for example up to 100 objects.

The only related solution I see here is to limit the PHP POST size via `post_max_size` option, however, it's not what I am looking for. Does anyone know how to set a proper validation rule for this case?

I'm using Laravel8.

Comment: Wrong way round, leave `post_max_size` alone. Stuff in the POST is controlled by what you place in your form or how you build the data for an ajax call. _I am tempted to say, if you dont build it, they wont come_

Comment: You can use     `"arr_param" => ["required","array","min:2","max:4"], // validate an array contains minimum 2 elements and maximum 4`

Comment: @DerekPollard But that does not stop 1000 occurances being sent though does it. I thought that was what the question was about

Comment: @RiggsFolly Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

To extend a bit on the answer already given by Derek, you can just use the laravel validator to validate your request. This validator also contains the min and max size options.

For more info see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#available-validation-rules

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know about the validation rules. The point is that there's no validation rule that will validate the array in the root of the POST body. At least I've not found one.

Comment: Just updated the question to reflect this idea.

Comment: If i understand well something like the size of $request->all();?

Comment: Not just the size of `$request->all();`, but the size of the array in the root of the POST request body.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your **custom rule** in **laravel**:

1- First Create a custom rule with **artisan command**:

```
php artisan make:rule ArrayCheck
```

2- Go to **app/Rules** folder and Edit **ArrayCheck.php**:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class ArrayCheck implements Rule {
    
    public function passes($attribute, $value) {
        return count($value) <= 10;
    }

    
    public function message() {
        return 'Your Array is bigger than our limits!';
    }
}
```

3- Then you can use your custom rule every where you want:

```php
use App\Rules\ArrayCheck;

$request->validate([
    'hobbies' => ['required', new ArrayCheck],
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you tell me please, to what field in the example from my question should I apply this new rule?

Comment: Why do this when the `size` rule is already there?